# Ruby on Rails 4 find object by id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following show-view, where i display basic information about Product and display other User's Products.

```
<h1>Book <%= @product.name %></h1>
<% @products.each do |product| %>
<ul>
    <%= product.name %>
    <%= link_to "Make offer", {controller: "offers", :action => 'create', id: product.id }    %>
</ul>
```

Controller

```
def show
    @product = current_user.products.find(params[:id])
    @products = Product.all
end
```

My goal is to make Offer between two Products. 
I created Offer model and methods for making Offers:

```
class Offer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product

  belongs_to :exchanger, class_name: "Product", foreign_key: "exchanger_id" 

  validates :product_id, :exchanger_id, presence: true

  def self.request(product, exchanger)
    unless product == exchanger or Offer.exists?(product, exchanger)
    transaction do
      create(product: product, exchanger: exchanger, status: "oczekujace")
      create(product: exchanger, exchanger: product, status: "oferta")
    end
  end
  #other methods 
end
```

Making offers is working, because I checked it in Console.
My problem is in OffersController:

```
class OffersController < ApplicationController
 before_filter :setup_products

 def create
   Offer.request(@prod, @exchanger)
   redirect_to root_path
 end

 private

 def setup_products
   @prod = current_user.products.find(1)
   @exchanger = Product.find_by_id(params[:id])
 end
end
```

Problem is with a following line (using link in show-page for products with different id's than 1 works):

```
@prod = current_user.products.find(1)
```

But I don't know how to find object in Db for actual product which my show-page shows. Not only for id = 1.

Comment: add error msg also.. I guess you don't have record with product id `1` for this user

Comment: do you have a **product with id=1 which belongs to your current user**?

Comment: With a code shown above I don't have a problem. It works. I have user with id = 1. Problem is that when i click link on my show page, my params[:id] is set on current Product id, with is ok. The second line in setup_products works. Problem is with first line. I'd like to get object for actual Product witch my page show and I don't know how to do that. I don't know how to find this object i database.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> **I don't know how to find this object in database.**

I don't know the specific answer to your question, but perhaps if I explain what you need to look at, your solution will arise:

---

**Find**

Rails isn't magic - it uses [ActiveRecord](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) (which is an [`ORM - Object-Relation Mapper`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping)), which means every time you fire a query (through `find`), your ORM (ActiveRecord) will search the relevant database data for you

The problem you have is that although you're using the correct syntax for your lookup, you may not have a record with an `id` of `1` in your db.

`current_user.products.find(1)` tells ActiveRecord to scope the query around the current user, and their products. So you'll get something like like this:

`SELECT * FROM 'products' WHERE user_id = '15' AND id = '1'`

---

**Objects**

Further, you have to remember that Ruby (and Rails by virtue of being built on Ruby) is an `object orientated` language. This means that *everything* you load / interact with in the language *should* be based on an object

The problem you have is you're not associating your object to your Rails framework correctly. What I mean here is described below, but essentially, if you build your Rails framework correctly, it will give you the ability to associate your objects with each other, allowing you to call the various `products` you need from your `offer`

This is a simplistic way of looking at it, of course. You'll want to look at this diagram to see how it works:

[image]

Bottom line - try treating your application like a series of objects, rather than a logical flow. This will help you appreciate the various associations etc that you need to get it moving forward

---

**Resources**

You mention you can't show the product on your show page for an `id` other than one. I think the problem is *really* about how to get your `show` action to work.

If this is the case, let me explain...

Rails is [resource-based](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default), meaning that everything you do / create *needs* to be centred around a resource (object) of some sort. The problem is many people don't know this, and consequently complicate their controller structure for no reason:

[image]

Above is the typical "CRUD" routing structure for Rails-based resources. This should demonstrate the way that Rails will typically be constructed -- *around* resources

--

Further, Rails is built on the [`MVC programming pattern`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) - meaning you need to use your controller to populate a series of data objects for use in your application.

To this end, if you load a resource, and want to populate it with resourceful information of another object - you *need* to make sure you have set up the data objects in a way to ensure you can look them up correctly, which either means passing the data through your routes or using a persistent data-type, such as [`cookies`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Cookies.html) or [`sessions`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.1.1/classes/ActionDispatch/Session/CookieStore.html)

---

The problem you have is **you need to pass the product id to your controller** somehow. How I'd do that is as follows (using [nested resources](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources)):

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :offers do
   resources :products #-> domain.com/offers/2/products
end
```

This will give you the ability to load the `products` controller with the variables `params[:id]` for the product, and `params[:offer_id]` for your `Offer` made available:

```
#app/controllers/products_controller.rb
Class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  def show
      @offer = Offer.find params[:offer_id]
      @product = Product.find params[:id]
  end
end
```